# Docker-compose AWS-CLI of dynamoDB is connecting before the dynamoDB local is up

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb

I followed the exact documentation here but I'm having the issue when I run docker-compose where the `app-node` is trying to connect before the dynamodb-local is fully up and running. I had to restart it to get it to connect. What's the issue here?
I used the exact code from the documentation:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
 dynamodb-local:
   command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ./data"
   image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
   container_name: dynamodb-local
   ports:
     - "8000:8000"
   volumes:
     - "./docker/dynamodb:/home/dynamodblocal/data"
   working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal
 app-node:
   depends_on:
     - dynamodb-local
   image: amazon/aws-cli
   container_name: app-node
   ports:
    - "8080:8080"
   environment:
     AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'DUMMYIDEXAMPLE'
     AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'DUMMYEXAMPLEKEY'
   command:
     dynamodb describe-limits --endpoint-url http://dynamodb-local:8000 --region us-west-2
```

I would get the error:
`Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://dynamodb-local:8000/"`
Running the container again after it fails would get it to work

Comment: The `dynamodb-local` image doesn't have a healthcheck configured. You might want to try adding one (found an [example here](https://github.com/amazon-archives/dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend/blob/master/src/test/resources/docker-compose.yml))

Comment: @phil thanks for finding that healthcheck, unfortunately the shell is deprecated for newer version of dynamoDB so I can't use that healthcheck.

Comment: 'app-node is trying to connect before the dynamodb-local is fully up and running' - how do you know? what's the logs?

Comment: I can simply rerun the container and it immediately works after it fails, I've added the logs to the question for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. Since the newer version of DynamoDB no longer accepts connections via `localhost:8000` nor the shell for `localhost:8000/shell`, it will always return a 400 status code. I added the healthcheck for the dynamoDB to wait for a returned 400 status code which would ensure the DB is ready for connection.

````
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          'if [ "$(curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w ''%{http_code}'' http://localhost:8000)" == "400" ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi',
        ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I build an waiter service for my docker-compose, put this as an depends_on to app-node.

```
waitTimer:
  image: busybox:1.28
  container_name: waitTimer
  command: sleep 5
```

Hope this helps.